# Bash text matching and writing

Tags: shell-script

I have multiple sequenced txt-files. They have specific data which I need to gather in one output file.

For Example:

1.txt

```
     Colour:    Red

     Hight:     10
```

2.txt

```
     Colour:    Blue

     Hight:     12
```

How can I use bash commands, such as sed/grep, to search for specific words and ignore some charachters in order to get the data, and put them in one output file.

For example:

out.txt

```
     Colour    Hight

      Red        10

      Blue       12
```

Thanks for helping
Anees

Comment: What have you tried so far? _"ignore some charachters"_ Which characters do you want to ignore?

Comment: Are we assuming  always 2 lines per input file, always in the same order?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are always 2 fields per file and always in the same order, Here's one way to do it with sed:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf '%s\t%s\n' Colour Hight

sed '

    / *Colour: */ {
        s///
        h
        n
    }

    / *Hight: */ {
        s///
        G
        s/\n/\t/g
    }

' "$@"
```

This answer uses the `hold space` feature of sed to save the data values from one line to the next.

We use statement grouping with `{` and `}`. All the commands in the group apply only to the addressed lines, in this case the lines selected by the patterns `/ *Colour */` and `/ *Hight */`.

On both the Colour and Hight lines, we first delete the text that was matched (`*Colour *` or `*Higth *`) with `s///`.

On the Colour line, we then hold `h` the remaining text in the *`hold space`*, and then skip to the next line of input without printing (`n`).

On the Hight line, we get/append `G` the contents of the hold space to the pattern space, concatenated with a newline '\n' by `sed`.  We then subsitute a tab `\t` for this newline and `sed` prints the output.

This answer should work with all versions of `sed`, whether on Linux, FreeBSD, or OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the header of the output file like
`echo 'Colour    Hight' > out.txt`
And then for each file you can do something like: 
`awk '{printf $2" ";next;}' 1.txt >> out.txt`
 
Or for all the txt files you can do:
`ls *.txt | xargs awk '{printf $2"  ";if (++onr%2 == 0) print "";next;}' >> out.txt`